# Possible risks of lowering 'limit_request' in Odoo 11 due to high memory usage?

Tags: multithreading, http, odoo, odoo-11, worker-service

I'm using Odoo 11 and have properly configured my server with thoses values:

```
limit_memory_hard = 20132659200
limit_memory_soft = 16777216000
limit_request = 8192
limit_time_cpu = 3600
limit_time_real = 600
limit_time_real_cron = 1200
max_cron_threads = 4
workers = 40
```

I recently increased the number of workers from 35 to 40 to meet the demands of my users effectively. However, I'm encountering high memory usage and considering lowering the 'limit_request' value to purge the workers more frequently. Currently, the workers are purged approximately once every 1.5 days, but I couldn't find any information about potential negative consequences, neither in the Odoo native code nor on the forums.

I'm thinking of reducing it from 8192 to 4096. Could someone please provide insights into the potential risks associated with this change? Any guidance or information on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The risk it's just to have your workers restarting more frequently than normal.
High memory usage could be lower in other ways depending on the customization or the nature of the business